# nova ERROR: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: openstack

I'm using Centos 6.5 x86_64 to setup Openstack Havana and all services work well. But when I've rebooted the operating system, I've founded that the  nova service does not work properly, the following error triggered:

```
nova flavor-list
ERROR: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Reviewing the log files in / var / log / nova gives the following error:

```
2014-03-24 12:24:04.293 6275 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [-] (6275) wsgi starting up  
2014-03-24 12:24:04.297 6267 CRITICAL nova [-] [Errno 98] Address already in use 
2014-03-24 12:24:04.412 6275 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Parent process has died unexpectedly, exiting 
2014-03-24 12:24:04.412 6274 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Parent process has died unexpectedly, exiting 
2014-03-24 12:24:04.412 6275 INFO nova.wsgi [-] Stopping WSGI server. 
2014-03-24 12:24:04.412 6274 INFO nova.wsgi [-] Stopping WSGI server.
```

The state of my  OpenStack server

```
nova-manage service list

Binary           Host                                 Zone             Status     State Updated_At
nova-cert        controller                           internal         enabled    :-)   2014-03-24 14:28:03
nova-consoleauth controller                           internal         enabled    :-)   2014-03-24 14:28:01
nova-scheduler   controller                           internal         enabled    :-)   2014-03-24 14:28:00
nova-conductor   controller                           internal         enabled    :-)   2014-03-24 14:27:59
nova-compute     controller                           nova             enabled    :-)   2014-03-24 14:28:06
nova-network     controller                           internal         enabled    :-)   2014-03-24 14:27:58

keystone service-list

+----------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
|                id                |   name   |   type   |        description        |
+----------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| 7ce108d652ee48d7897127045a371795 |  cinder  |  volume  |   Cinder Volume Service   |
| 9452b875328f4763b7766eb533bd75c4 | cinderv2 | volumev2 |  Cinder Volume Service V2 |
| e9607d1a308140298f8364fd2a0e62a8 |  glance  |  image   |    Glance Image Service   |
| b7ac07f69e2e41f684d6470c69db4781 | keystone | identity | Keystone Identity Service |
| cbdfa73329094d7d94c7464b9bf0ef7d |   nova   | compute  |    Nova Compute service   |
+----------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+

ps -ef | grep "nova-api"

nova      2522     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-api-metadata --logfile /var/log/nova/metadata-api.log
root     11909  6217  0 15:11 pts/1    00:00:01 gedit nova-api.log
root     12644  3832  0 15:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep nova-api


netstat -napo | grep 877

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8775                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2522/python         off (0.00/0/0)
```

Any pointers would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

firstly, i strongly recommend you to find or ask for answer on ask.openstack.org

then from what you described, it may caused by: you've enabled nova-api-metadata and nova-api service in the same time.

from the default configuration we know that: ['ec2', 'osapi_compute', 'metadata'] are enabled, see https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/stable/havana/nova/service.py#L55

so it will start each service one by one when nova-api service is called, see https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/stable/havana/nova/cmd/api.py#L45

since nova-api-metadata service is running, which cause the 8775 port is used, then one service launched by nova-api will die and since this exception is not caught, then the other two will die too, then you get what you see in the log

If what I've assumed is right, please cancel the nova-api-metadata service and use nova-api service only, which means 'chkconfig openstack-nova-api-metadata off; chkconfig openstack-nova-api on', i'm not sure about the specific service name on your system, but should be something like that, correct it if i'm wrong

Comment: Wow! This was it! I had to search for more than an hour to get hold of this answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused is a common error encountered everytime. One of the case is keystone is refusing the connection for the nova service.

make sure SERVICE_PASSWORD for nova and quantum are same while creating the keystone services.Go to quantum and nova config files and verify the SERVICE_PASSWORD are same.

Njoy!!